# How can I show questions I've asked on my personal website?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, support

Is there any way to show questions that I have asked in my personal website?

Like the flair, I shall like to have a widget that I can include in my website [removed spam URL] and let the visitors click and reach Stack Overflow if they are interested.

Comment: Hmm, interesting idea! Like a flair for questions.

Comment: Let us name it qFlair!

Comment: A somewhat related service is [Stack2Blog](http://stackapps.com/questions/611/stack2blog-turning-your-answers-into-blogs-for-sale)

Comment: or [StackTack](http://stackapps.com/questions/518/stacktack-a-javascript-widget-you-can-stick-anywhere) for individual questions

Comment: Kind of like how questions are handled in chat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a JSON list pretty easily using StackApps' [`/users/{id}/questions`](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/user-questions).

So you could just do a jQuery `$.get` for `http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/143541/questions` and do what you want with it from there.

[Get an API key](https://stackapps.com/apps/register) before going live with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its great to know this.

Comment: Everybody (whoever learns from this) please vote-up @bemace for this nice answer.